# Get http request or session object in spring xml

Tags: spring

I know how to autowire a http request object in Java code:

```
@Resource
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

I want to do something similar in the xml conf. The bean I'm trying to instantiate takes a http session object as constructor argument:

```
    <bean class="..." scope="request">
        <constructor-arg>
             ???
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a factory class that uses this method:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#currentRequestAttributes%28%29

E.g.:

```
<bean id="httpSessionFactory" class="HttpSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg>true</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="..." scope="request">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean factory-bean="httpSessionFactory"
              factory-method="getSession"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And the Java:

```
public class HttpSessionFactory {
    private boolean create;

    public HttpSessionFactory(boolean create) {
        this.create = create;
    }

    public static HttpSession getSession() {
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return attr.getRequest().getSession(create);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to reference the HttpServletRequest object directly from xml? After all, it can be autowired in Java.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You could wrap the code above into a Spring namespace such that you had a <session/> tag that resolved to the current session. But I don't know of another way. Usually you shouldn't/don't need to access these objects directly and let Spring manage the beans/scopes.